# 'L1_ratio' and 'C' in sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run elastic net with the saga solver. However, I'm confused as to what the 'C' parameter does. As far as I can tell, the L1_ratio is the convex sum of lasso and ridge penalties – the L1 and L2 norms - and should be used for elastic net regularization. Should I be setting 'C' to 0 when I set a number for 'L1_ratio'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C` is the hyperparameter ruling the amount of regularisation in your model; see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Its inverse `1/C` is called the regularisation strength in the doc. The larger `C` the less penalty for the parameters norm, `l1` or `l2`. `C` cannot be set to `0` by the way, it has to be `>0`.

`l1_ratio` is a parameter in a `[0,1]` range weighting `l1` vs `l2` regularisation. Hence the amount of `l1` regularisation is `l1_ratio * 1./C`, likewise the amount of `l2` reg is `(1-l1_ratio) * 1./C`